# To write a program to remove duplicates from an array

Tags: c++

I am working on program that remove duplicates from an array I am using three functions here: one to take the input such as the size and the number, second function to remove duplicates and return the number without duplicates and the third function just a report show the size and the new number but I am having problem I don't know in what step I think in report or phillip erreur:

> In function `‘int main()’`: invalid conversion from `‘int*’` to `‘int’`,initializing argument 1 of `‘void report(int, int)’`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int size = 100;

void phillip(int[], int & );
/* Preconditions: Array of base type in declared and int varuable declared
   postconditions: the array is filled with values supllied by the user at
   the keybord. the user is assked how many values they want - this value is
   given to the second argument.
*/

int remdubs(int[], int noel);
/* Preconditions: An array of basetype int that  has noel values.
   postconditions: The number of unique elemts in the array is returned. The function removes all dubplicates inside the array.
*/

void report(int s, int d);

int main()
{
    int ruby[size];
    int numele, numuniq;

    phillip(ruby, numele);

    numuniq = remdubs(ruby, numele);

    report(ruby, numuniq);

    return 0;
}

void phillip(int[], int& )
{
    int s;
    cout << "\nHow many values you want? ";
    cin >> s;

    cout << "\nPlease input 10 integers, hitting return after each one \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        int num;
        cin >> num;
    }
}

int rembups(int sapphire[], int noel)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < noel; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < noel; j++)
        {

            if (sapphire[i] == sapphire[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < noel; k++)
                    sapphire[k] = sapphire[k + 1];

                noel--;

                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return noel;
}

void report(int s, int d)
{
    cout << "\nYou entered " << s << "distinct numbers: " << d;
}
```

Comment: If this isn't homework I recommend using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). Even if it _is_ homework I still recommend using them.

Comment: I have enough there i dont want to use vector i just want to fix that code

Answer (score 2):

Can't explain it better than your error:

```
void report (int s, int d);
```

this function asks for two integer values, you're passing an array to it which, with decayed functionalities, will behave like an integer pointer

```
int ruby[size];
report (ruby, numuniq);
```

I'm unsure on the behavior of your program but you should rather do something like

```
report(ruby[0], numuniq);
```

that is: access the element of the array and feed it to the function

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the function report, it asks for two integer and you are passing an array and an integer instead
and again i don't think you need 2 parameters in the function report one would solve your purpose

`void report(int d)
{
    cout << "\nYou entered <<d<<" distinct numbers";
}`

that would solve your error but i don't think you would get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Few problems with the code:

- `Report` function should be expecting an array of integers rather than single integer
- Try using human readable variable or function names
- `remdubs` was renamed to `rempubs` in function definition
- phillip function definition didn't have params defined properly
- You have `const int size` but do not use it
- `remdups` has a bug somewhere. I will leave that out as I am trying to fix other issues here.
- There are better ways of finding duplicates than `remdups`. Please look at some other solutions.

**I have fixed your code and provided it [here on ideone](http://ideone.com/a0QsrK)**